# Why does my form keep repeating? It seems like the php isn't running

Tags: php, html

I have a file called form.php and when I upload it to my server, that supports php, the form keeps on repeating and never executes the php code. I uploaded it at http://davidjahn.info/DavidJahnNet/form.php

```
 <?php
 $age=$_POST["age"];
 echo $age;
 ?>

 <html>
    <head>
        <title>Survey</title>
        <style type="text/css">
            .welcome {
                color: #FFFFFF;
                text-align: center;
                background-color:red;
                font-weight:bold;
                height: 50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table style="height: 232px; width: 500px">
            <form method="post" id="survey" action="form.php">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div class="welcome"><br>Welcome!</div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <br>
                            <br>
                            <div id="question1" style="display: inline;">
                                <h3>
                                    Are You 30+ Years Old?
                                </h3>
                                <div style="height: 10px"></div>
                                <input type="button" name="age" value="Yes" onclick="document.getElementById('question1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('question2').style.display='inline';">
                                <input type="button" name="age" value="No" onclick="document.getElementById('question1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('question2').style.display='inline';">
                            </div>
                            <div id="question2" style="display: none;">
                                <h3>
                                    Are You Looking for a Date?
                                </h3>
                                <div style="height: 10px"></div>
                                <input type="button" name="date" value="Yes" onclick="document.getElementById('question2').style.display='none';document.getElementById('question3').style.display='inline';">
                                <input type="button" name="date" value="No" onclick="document.getElementById('question2').style.display='none';document.getElementById('question3').style.display='inline';">
                            </div>
                            <div id="question3" style="display: none;">
                                <h3>
                                    Which Girl Is Your Type?
                                </h3>
                                <div style="height: 10px"></div>
                                <input type="image" src="http://healthystartups.com/storage/600px-MA_Route_1.png?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1319542839834" alt="Submit" width="100px" value="type1" />
                                <input type="image" src="http://jenntgrace.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/2.png" alt="Submit" width="100px" value="type2" />
                                <input type="image" src="http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Q_owQUxNjdQ/Te3ALCmT3oI/AAAAAAAAAnk/wv9r0b0MT-g/s1600/600px-MA_Route_3.svg_.jpg" alt="Submit" width="100px" value="type3" />
                                <input type="image" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-wY_qFr2pcAs/UCxhAayJ6oI/AAAAAAAAC6w/PgtLs2O_4g8/s1600/4.png" alt="Submit" width="100px" value="type4" />
                            </div>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </form>
        </table>
    </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: The first four lines of php are:

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt: There is, the code was formatted incorrectly.

Comment: Take a look for Apache

Comment: I just reuploaded it to my server and now the form just repeates. http://davidjahn.info/DavidJahnNet/form.php

Comment: As a note: It's not polite or a good idea to hotlink images from various places on the web. Consider saving those images and hosting them yourself.

Comment: What exactly are you expecting to happen? Your php code simply spits out whatever submitted in the `age` field, then "execution" goes right on to your form again.

Comment: I want to be able to store each choice as a variable as shown with age. Then I want to be able to redirect to a different site based on variables.

Comment: @DaveChen Please don't spam "see my answer" comments. We can all see your answer, including the person who asked the question.

Comment: Got it! I think he's gone though. :P

Answer (score 7):

PHP is a server-side language. You need a server running PHP to write PHP pages. You can't simply save them and open them in your browser.

Look into something like [XAMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XAMPP) which will get you up-and-running quickly with a development environment.

Comment: I had the same opinion on the first look of the question, but in fact the problem is more related to the structure of the HTML / JavaScript elements in this case.

Comment: I threw away that assumption when I looked at the source. No PHP tags found :)

Answer (score 1):

Are you testing this on localhost ? I think you don't have WAMP installed and you are trying to view .php file without php server & you must know that php is server side language. Install EasyPHP and then you will be able to run .php

http://www.easyphp.org/

Comment: I had the same opinion on the first look of the question, but in fact the problem is more related to the structure of the HTML / JavaScript elements in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You should use buttons for submitting. I have edited your code to do the following:

- buttons that have cover images of the four types
- hidden values to represent age, date

Code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST['age'])) {
        $age=$_POST["age"];
        echo $age;
    }
?>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Survey</title>
      <style type="text/css">
         .welcome {
             color: #FFFFFF;
             text-align: center;
             background-color:red;
             font-weight:bold;
             height: 50px;
         }
         .type1 {
             background-image: url(http://healthystartups.com/storage/600px-MA_Route_1.png?__SQUARESPACE_CACHEVERSION=1319542839834); 
         }
         .type2 {
             background-image: url(http://jenntgrace.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/2.png);
         }
         .type3 {
             background-image: url(http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-Q_owQUxNjdQ/Te3ALCmT3oI/AAAAAAAAAnk/wv9r0b0MT-g/s1600/600px-MA_Route_3.svg_.jpg);
         }
         .type4 {
             background-image: url(http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-wY_qFr2pcAs/UCxhAayJ6oI/AAAAAAAAC6w/PgtLs2O_4g8/s1600/4.png);
         }
         input[type=submit]{
             border: none;
             width: 100px;
             height: 100px;
             background-size:cover;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <table style="height: 232px; width: 500px">
         <form method="post" id="survey" action="form.php">
            <input type="hidden" name="age" id="age">
            <input type="hidden" name="date" id="date">
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <div class="welcome"><br>Welcome!</div>
               </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>
                  <ul>
                     <br>
                     <br>
                     <div id="question1" style="display: inline;">
                        <h3>
                           Are You 30+ Years Old?
                        </h3>
                        <div style="height: 10px"></div>
                        <input type="button" value="Yes" onclick="document.getElementById('question1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('question2').style.display='inline';document.getElementById('age').value='Yes'">
                        <input type="button" value="No" onclick="document.getElementById('question1').style.display='none';document.getElementById('question2').style.display='inline';document.getElementById('age').value='No'">
                     </div>
                     <div id="question2" style="display: none;">
                        <h3>
                           Are You Looking for a Date?
                        </h3>
                        <div style="height: 10px"></div>
                        <input type="button" value="Yes" onclick="document.getElementById('question2').style.display='none';document.getElementById('question3').style.display='inline';document.getElementById('date').value='Yes'">
                        <input type="button" name="date" value="No" onclick="document.getElementById('question2').style.display='none';document.getElementById('question3').style.display='inline';document.getElementById('date').value='No'">
                     </div>
                     <div id="question3" style="display: none;">
                        <h3>
                           Which Girl Is Your Type?
                        </h3>
                        <div style="height: 10px"></div>
                        <input type="submit" value="1" class="type1" name="type" />
                        <input type="submit" value="2" class="type2" name="type" />
                        <input type="submit" value="3" class="type3" name="type" />
                        <input type="submit" value="4" class="type4" name="type" />
                     </div>
                  </ul>
               </td>
            </tr>
         </form>
      </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Then why isn't it posting age?

Comment: @DavidJahn Because buttons doesn't post a value. Your `age` elements are buttons. See my answer.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg: Exactly. I have covered that in my **updated** answer :)

Comment: Change the names of the age and date buttons and you are good to go.

Comment: Removed the names from the buttons.

Comment: why don't you want names on the buttons. How am I going to distinguish the two in the $_POST.

Comment: I am using hidden input values. Please check your post output, it should return `age`, `date`, and `type`.

Comment: `age` and `date` will both return either `Yes` or `No` while `type` will return a number from 1 to 4.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running your code on a `localhost` server because **PHP** only works on server side not client side.
If you are running it correctly use this for better practice:

```
if(isset($_POST['age'])){
$age=$_POST["age"];
 echo $age;
}
```

Comment: An even better practice would be to escape user-supplied content before outputting. And, first of all, not mispell $_POST

Answer (score 0):

Your Javascript and HTML doesn't make much sense if you are looking for the age field.

The `age` elements that you have are two buttons.

You could solve this by using `<input type="hidden" name="age" value="">` and then modifying the value of this using Javascript, when the user clicks your buttons (if you do this, change the name attribute of your buttons).

OR you could solve it by replacing the buttons with radio buttons.

Simply replace `<input type="button" name="age" ...`

with `<input type="radio" name="age" ...>`

Answer (score -3):

I'm not sure what you're trying to say. Could you elaborate a bit more?

On the other hand, by taking a rough guess, it could be your browser. Try add

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

above

```
<html>
```

EDIT: If you're talking about PHP printing rather than doing what it's meant to do. Well just to let you know, PHP is a server side scripting language. It needs to be processed via PHP engine. Are you on a shared web host or did you setup your own server?